# Is my database and framework understanding wrong?

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp, database-design, relational-database

I just started to learn cakePHP few days ago and it confuses me a lot. If I would write project from scratch, my system would have lets say users and each user would have one profile. So I would create database tables like this:

```
+----+----------+----------+------------+
| id | username | password | profile_id |
+----+----------+----------+------------+
|  1 | ksno     | ksno     |          1 |
|  2 | cake     | bake     |          2 |
+----+----------+----------+------------+

+----+-----------+----------+---------------+
| id | firstname | lastname |   birthday    |
+----+-----------+----------+---------------+
|  1 | Alex      |          | in few months |
|  2 | cake      | PHP      |               |
+----+-----------+----------+---------------+
```

And then I could create a profile entity from an user. The problem is, I have to create profile first, because table users has foreign key of profile. Fine, I would just start a transaction and commit after everything was created successfully. That is how I learned it...

But if I take a look at [cakePHP docs and book](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongsto-associations):

> If a Table contains a foreign key, it belongs to the other Table.

So that basically means... User belongs to profile? But it doesn't. I'm almost done with my CRUD actions on user and its profile.... But I feel like I'm doing something wrong... Following the book... We could save an entity and its associations from form like this:

```
$entity = $users->newEntity($this->request->data(), [
    'associated' => [
        'Profiles' => ['validate' => false],
    ]
]);
```

But it requires to change my database schema which would lead me to misunderstand what is going on, because I cant first save user without having profile id... So I went and did this:

```
$userProfilesRepository = TableRegistry::get('UserProfiles');
$userProfile = $userProfilesRepository->newEntity();
$userProfile = $userProfilesRepository->patchEntity($userInfo, $this->request->data);
$user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
if ($userProfilesRepository->save($userInfo) && $this->Users->save($user->set('profile_id', $userInfo->get('id')))) {...
```

Can someone please help point me to the right way of thinking about database schemes and frameworks associations? I feel like I'm doing wrong, but just because I struggle in cakePHP.

Comment: Your tables are reasonable. Frameworks like CakePHP and others that use object-relational mappers force you into a network data model, a naive and limited way of thinking that harks back to pre-relational days. Much of what can be done in SQL is unsupported by such frameworks. I suggest you study different data models (network, entity-relationship and relational) since knowledge of their restrictions and the ability to translate between them should clarify a lot of the issues you're facing.

Comment: Does such frameworks change my developement workflow somehow? I firstly made ER-Models and then based on those, created my database, then started to learn cakePHP and write my application. But then it comes to this point, where I feel doing wrong and thinking: should I start in other way ? Or should I just re-design my database so that it is compatible with the framework ?

Comment: I long ago decided to give up on object-relational mappers (and frameworks that depend on them). Data modeling and systems modeling are separate disciplines. I make classes for system responsibilities and deal with data in sets, so I have no restrictions on how I model my data. Unfortunately, I can't help you work within the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have the relation backwards. You should not have a `profile_id` field in the `users` table; you should have a `user_id` field in the `profiles` table. Then, the profile "belongs to" the user, which probably makes more sense to you.

Comment: That could be true, but lets say user 'hasOne' profile, not profile 'belongsTo' user.... Why would I save FK in profile table if user has a profile, user should know which profile it has, but not profile should know on which user it depends... What if I want to make a profile without a user? But still would force every user have a profile. That is what me confuses.

Comment: Saying user `hasOne` profile and profile `belongsTo` user are the same, as far as Cake is concerned; it's the same database structure viewed from the two sides. You can make a profile without a user by just having `user_id` null in the profiles table.

Comment: @ksno "user should know which profile it has" is false reasoning. The *user of the dabase* should know. Relevant application relationships are "user ID has name NAME and password PASSWORD", "profile ID has real name FIRSTNAME LASTNAME and birthdate BIRTHDATE" and "user USER_ID has profile PROFILE_ID". You can choose to easily combine the latter two into a table "profile ID has real name FIRSTNAME LASTNAME and birthdate BIRTHDATE" and user USER_ID has profile ID". But combining the first two give a complicated meaning involving NULL and requires a more complicated constraint than just a FK.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to save the user profile and associate the user with it

```
$userProfilesRepository = TableRegistry::get('Profiles');

  $data = [
        'firstname' => 'FOO',
        'lastname' => 'BAR',
        'user' => [
           'username'=>'foo',
           'password'=>'bar'
        ]
    ]; // Dummy data

$entity = $userProfilesRepository->newEntity($data, [
    'associated' => [
        'Users' => ['validate' => false],
    ]
]);
```

It will create the user profile first and then then save the association.
I hope this will clear it.

Answer (score 0):

ORMs are problematic and don't get the relational model. Nevertheless: Design your database then *describe* it via the ORM "relationships" [sic]. "Belongs to" is just a name for a declaration. That choice of name is inspired by the situtaton where a weak ER entity type (possibly associative) has a FK in its PK to the PK of another "owning" entity type to which it "belongs". Just use the declarations that put the FKs where you want them. Don't fret about spelling.

(You can think of some record/model declarations as describing computed columns for its corresponding table which are only in the schema in another table.)

Re your design: As far as ER is concered, users having optional profiles suggests the straightforward schema where profiles are weak entities with FKs to users they "belong to". But you are thinking of having a *nullable* profile FK in users, which would also require the constraint that *every profile appears as a FK in exactly one user*. This is an unnecessarily complicated design. The simple design is to put the FK in the profile table, which agrees with "profile belongs to user".